# Error: No Keyring found for the requested account

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

I am an student and in this moment practicing how to create a simple smart contract in remix.ethereum.org.

I got compiled the small program with function get without problem.

When I deploy the program the Metamask provide an error in the title of this question. The environment Injected Web 3 is correct and my account is connected properly.

I am not an expert, I am following a simple exercise provided by my institutions.

Regards